# Handle IRQ in Debian

Tags: debian, hp, interrupts, irq

I'm running Debian and I'm running into an IRQ problem, two cards that generate a lot of IRQ interrupts are sharing the same IRQ (16). I found on the HP Bios an option that states "allow OS to trip IRQ", I enable it, but how do I actually change the IRQ from the OS?

Comment: Man, I haven't seen a question about IRQs in years, not since the days of setting a jumper on those bloody NE2000 Compatible ISA network cards and then going to the Windows 3.11 Network properties to update the IRQ and then finding out that the SoundBlaster 16 was also using IRQ7, so you'd swap it for IRQ3 and disable the on-board COM port to use it.

Comment: Yes, baaad memories... :-/

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of this: http://serverfault.com/questions/70585/manually-assign-a-pci-card-to-an-interrupt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Farseeker, it has been many eons since I had to play with IRQ conflicts, and I always tried to find a way to make sure no two devices shared an IRQ if I could help it as nothing good ever comes from it.

I would read the docs for both cards and figure out how to move one of them to another IRQ. This used to be done with jumpers on the physical hardware, those days are pretty much gone and these days you use the manufacturer's setup / diagnostic programs to change the firmware to change the IRQ's.

There might not be a utility for Debian for this, you might need to pop it into a PC running Windoze to change it, and then move it back to your Debian box.

Comment: Im running an HP ml150, but the bios is useless doesn't have any item related to Plug and Play or IRQ assignment. Does this server allows to configure this from windows?

Comment: How old is this server? Is it an ML150 G1? G3? We're assuming you're using the PCI interface here. Are you using PCI or ISA? I'm fairly sure that the ML150 is too new to have any ISAs but you never know...

Comment: You were right, the IRQ misses I was seeing were normal misses that happened during boot up, so the problem wasn't IRQ but unstable drivers

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu system (and probably your Debian system) have (or you can `apt-get` them) `lspci` and `setpci`. I would start by reading their `man` pages.